# CSS - double spaced text but single space text selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

Double space can be achieved using CSS with `line-height:2em`, which also makes text selection doubles when you drag on it. Is there any way to have text selection not include extra padding that occurs from CSS line-height, just like how it would look like when you drag what I have wrote here?

I have the following options:

1. Divide paragraph into sentences, each with their own element, and push/pull words when overflow/underflow. (What I have implemented so far)
2. Make line-height 2em, disable default text selection, and draw text selection box with Javascript. It may still be complicated, but probably not as much as having to push/pull words on every text input.
3. There is this diabolically simple trick I am not aware of.

Comment: When I said 'what I have wrote here', I didn't realize StackOverflow replaces all newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple trick: use Firefox.

**Chrome**:

[image: Selection in Chrome]

**Firefox**:

[image: Selection in Firefox]

Comment: Of all these months of development in Chrome, I have not realized that there actually is this other browser that handles it the way I want...